# How to set up this relationship on the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, relationship

I have a list of records in my database, each one containing several categories from a total of 200 possible categories.
There is a view on the database where the calls can be searched. They are listed grouped by category, following this model:

| Records | Categories |
| --- | --- |
| Record1 | Category1 |
| Record1 | Category2 |
| Record1 | Category3 |
| Record2 | Category1 |
| Record2 | Category2 |
| Record2 | Category4 |

Now I need to add to this view one column for each category, marking what calls have what categories, like so:

| Records | Categories | Category1 | Category2 | Category3 | Category4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Record1 | Category1 | X | X | X |  |
| Record1 | Category2 | X | X | X |  |
| Record1 | Category3 | X | X | X |  |
| Record2 | Category1 | X | X |  | X |
| Record2 | Category2 | X | X |  | X |
| Record2 | Category4 | X | X |  | X |

How would I start to build this relationship and to add it to the existing view

Comment: What options have you considered? What are you stuck on? And why does the first row of record 2 not have category 2 ticked? This is an anti-pattern you realise, so its not the best way to do things.

Comment: I have considered doing some joins, but that would be quite a task to do it by hand, one for each of the 200 categories and I do not know of a way to make it recurrent

Comment: This is not a job for a `VIEW` it's a job for your presentation layer. If you added, or removed, a category, your `VIEW`s definition would immediately be out of date.

Comment: @Larnu, yes I agree. The thing is that we are going to use the data on Tableau to make a dashboard. A version of Tableau imbeded in another software so it doesn't have all the functionalities of the full one. 
I don't have experience working wtih Tableau, I feel like this should be possible to do it without all the columns but don't know how

Comment: This kind of a denormalized query will require dynamic sql. That eliminates a view as an option.

Comment: It will almost certainly be much easier to do in Tableau - its designed for this sort of thing. SQL isn't.

Comment: Well, not saying this would be a good idea, but you could _dynamically_ re-create the view every time a new category was added (or once a {some time period}).

Comment: @DaleK the first row of record 2 has been corrected. That was my mistake